# Why does the same ping command behave completely different on two systems?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, ping, raspberry-pi

**The Software**

Ubuntu Server:

```
ubuntu@server: $ cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=wily
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.10"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="15.10 (Wily Werewolf)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 15.10"
VERSION_ID="15.10"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

ubuntu@server: $ ping -V
ping utility, iputils-s20121221
```

Raspberry Pi 1 Model B:

```
pi@raspberrypi: $ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

pi@raspberrypi: $ ping -V
ping utility, iputils-s20121221
```

**The expected outcome**

```
ubuntu@server: $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=17.3 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=17.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=14.1 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 received, 25% packet loss, time 3001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.172/15.922/17.340/1.312 ms
```

The important part is the missing package, this is as I would expect it, if a package is lost OR it takes to long the ping command should print a `Request timeout` message... but on the Raspberry Pi...

**The real outcome**

```
pi@raspberrypi: $ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=12.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=12.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=12.2 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=58 time=13.2 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 4 received, 20% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.289/12.724/13.284/0.397 ms
```

If you don't look close enough you may miss what is wrong. But it has `5 packets transmitted` but not printed an `Request timeout` or even gone to the next `icmp_seq`, it has just resend the missing package witout any error, and you will only ever find out if a packet went missing if you read the summary at the end.

**The question**

Why does the same `ping` version behave diffrent on diffrent systems?

Has the ping command a config somwhere that I can edit to make it behave the same?

Comment: If you run your ping a second time from the PI, do you see the same behavior?  That first packet could be missed because your system is arping for the default gateway.  But you would only see it the first time you ping with a clear arp table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand what you want me to do. But I have run the Pi without the `-c` option for an entire night and it missed a few hunderet packages, but I didn't get any `Request timeout` messages. I could just see the missing packages in the summary at the end.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to get you to understand this.  http://blog.ipspace.net/2007/04/why-is-first-ping-lost.html Which I think is what your problem is on the ping from 'pi'.  IE the first packet is being lost to an ARP.  I am not sure what your other problems are.

Comment: Ah, yes that would explain the one lost package. BUT my question just shows one short example result. As you can see from what is expect is a `Request timeout`, as my internet connection her unfortunately drops. Also I don't have perfect control to just drop one package so this is just a recreation. And as I said in my other comment: The Problem is not that ONE package is lost/too slow, but that I don't get a message if that happens like on the ubuntu server when a package is lost/too slow. I hope I made my Problem a bit more clear for you. ;) (I'll improve the question when I wake up 4am atm)

Comment: No, your question is not clear.  A ping has many ways to fail, and depending on the specific problem and network configuration of other devices on your network you will get different error messages.  You don't have enough information to make any useful statements about anything right now.

Comment: Yea, but I don't really have an idea on how to phrase it right now. Englisch is not my first language...